# How to get wordpress post If I uninstall wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp64

I installed windows 10 in my system without taking backup of wamp. But I get my wamp old files in Windows.old folder. Is there any way to get my wordpress posts and other files?

Comment: Do you have a database backup?

Comment: no, where is the files stored actually?

Comment: Hang on, writing an answer, you should be able to get everything back.....

Comment: What version of WAMPServer were you using?

Comment: 3.1.9 I think. I am checking my old files. If there any way to know version from wamp files?

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows install kept all of the WAMP folder intact and you can copy it back to the same drive (C: I assume) that it was originally installed on, then YES, probably.

#### Install the MSVC Runtimes

First step is to make sure you have ALL the MSVC Runtime libraries installed. In reality you probably dont need then all, but it is simpler to put them all there (they are used by other software as well) than trying to add the specific ones you need.

The simplest way to do this is to go to the [WAMPServer backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and download the ZIP file containing all the MSVC Runtimes. The link is right at the bottom of the page and is called

```
All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)
```

Extract that somewhere and install both the 32bit and 64bit runtimes ONE AT A TIME in logical version number order, oldest version first.

#### Reinstate the old files

Copy the complete wamp folder and all sub folders from Windows.old to C:\ *(or whereever it was originally installed)*.

#### Reinstall the Apache and MySQL Services

Now run the `\wamp64\wampmanager.exe` and then use the wampmanager menu in the System tray to do

- left click -> Apache -> Service Adminitration -> Install Service
- left click -> MySQL -> Service Adminitration -> Install Service

If you also want mariaDB

- left click -> MySQL -> Service Adminitration -> Install Service

This should put everything back as it was before.

You may also need to check you HOSTS file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to make sure localhost is not commented (Windows10 does that for some reason).

If you have any Virtual Hosts defined, they will also need to be added here again

Minimum default content though should be

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

Comment: there is no MySQL, but apache and mariadB there. what to do?

Comment: MySQL tray icon still in red.?

Comment: Were you using MySQL or mariaDB as your DBMS?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I am using Wordpress, that's all. But I think I have used MySql

Comment: Do you see anything in the error logs? Actually you can tell what you were using by looking at old entries in the error logs

Comment: Also check "Windows Event Viewer" for messages from APACHE or MYSQL or mariaDB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214822/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-vijay-ram).

Comment: I don't get any error logs. But wamp tray icon is red.